# How to retrieve data within a 6 day time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve the data between a 6 day time period.

The output I want is:

```
Date
--------
2019-05-01
2019-05-04
2019-06-01
2019-06-06
2019-07-01
```

This is my query so far:

```sql
select date from data d
where CAST(d.createdate as Date) between CAST('2019-05-01' as Date) 
AND DATEADD(CAST(dd,6,'2016-07-01') as Date)
```

Why is this not retrieving the results I want?

Comment: Why did not you run the SQL and find out? This seems like it's pretty simple for you to check.

Comment: I think there is an inconsistency between your code and your question. Why doesn't your select query cover six days?

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with your query.

The first is with your `DATEADD` statement which is all mixed up. You are not nesting the casted date into the statement properly. This is the corrected version:

```
DATEADD(dd, 6, CAST('2016-07-01' as Date))
```

The second is that your `select` projection refers to the column `date` which does not exist. Instead, you probably want your `createdate` column.

The third is that your `between` clause is back to front. You are saying between `2019-05-01` and `2016-07-01` but the smaller date must come first.

In fact, your given example is incorrect. In your question, you say "want to retrieve the data between two dates only for 6 days." So, why would you start with a date in 2016 and then jump to a date in 2019 and add 6 days to the date in 2019? If you want to use the `DATEADD` approach, you need to use the same date in both positions.

So here is your corrected query:

```
select d.createdate from data d
where CAST(d.createdate as Date) between CAST('2019-05-01' as Date) 
AND DATEADD(dd, 6, CAST('2019-05-01' as Date))
```